# Is there a way to run an IPFS daemon on heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, ipfs

I have a Django app on Heroku that needs to interact with IPFS. 
has anyone found a way to run a IPFS daemon? It is needed in order for the python IPFS API to be able to read and write files from IPFS.

Google searches for IPFS on Heroku are useless.

Perhaps there is an obvious way to start a IPFS daemon process alongside my Django app, But I could not figure out how to set this up, that is, if it's at all possible.

Comment: I was looking up alternatives and maybe migrating my app to a container is the best way

Comment: Not heroku but we have a guide on how to deploy to fly.io https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k1Hcg3B43Q4&t=3s